# Spring 4 JPA @Column bypasses setter function

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've a working program using Spring 4, JPA, Hibernate and MySQL and I'm applying JUnit tests to the program as a learning exercise.

On an entity class I've mapped a field:

```
@Column(name="processCode")
private String processCode = null;

public void setProcessCode(String code) { this.processCode = Utilities.setNotNull(code); }
```

(Utilities.java contains some helper functions.  setNotNull(String code) is something like "return (code == null) ? "" : code;")

When I create an object through memory a null "code" is turned into a blank processCode:

```
myObject.setProcessCode(null);
"".equals(myObject.getProcessCode());  // eval true
```

When I fetch the database record through JPA / Hibernate, and the field in the database has a null value, the field is null.

```
myObject = manager.find(MyObject.class, 1L);
myObject.getProcessCode() == null;  // eval true
```

That is, the DB fetching code directly fills the private attribute processCode and my setter isn't fired.

Can I force the manager.find() to use the setProcessCode() function?

Thanks,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by positioning `@Column(name="processCode")` over the getter method instead of annotation the field.

By default, you will have to use other mapping annotations over getter methods as well, in order for this to work (especially the the `@Id` annotation).

Comment: This works, but be wary.  I have columns with underscores, like "phone_number". It is used in HQL like " from User u where u.phone_number like '...' ".  When the Column is placed on the attribute this works OK. When the Column is on the getter my HQL must become " from User u where u.phoneNumber like '...' ". Otherwise I get "QueryException: could not resolve property: phone_number ...